# create text files with mtime between time range

Tags: perl

I found the below one-liner, that creates 50 text files

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -wE'
    path("dir/s".$_.".txt")->spew("some data...$_\n") for 1..50
```

but it creates all the files with mtime as current time.

Is it possible to have the mtime between a date range?. like Jan 2016 to Dec 2018 for the text files?.

I understand that I have to use Time::Piece module, but I don't see Time::Piece module in my RHEL Perl which is 5.010.

Comment: It looks like you can chain a call to the Path::Tiny `.touch($seconds)` method to set the mtime and atime of the files, but I can't test this right now.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Can I suggest you start by reading the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) documentation?

Comment: `"dir/s".$_.".txt"` is a weird way to write `"dir/s$_.txt"`.

Comment: @DaveCross.. I have been trying but I dont see Time::Piece module in my RHEL Perl which is 5.010..

Comment: Time::Piece was already core in Perl 5.10 (which itself is pretty ancient: 2007). Do you have both `perl` and `perl-core` packages installed?.

Comment: @melpomeme..  perl --version is giving ````This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi```` and ````perl -E ' use Time::Piece '```` gives ````Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 1```` do you think it is there?.. should I do something with the INC?..

Comment: Could you please answer the question I actually asked?

Comment: @melpomene.. pls pardon my ignorance... I dont know how to check that perl vs perl-core

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190522/discussion-between-melpomene-and-stack0114106).

Comment: It's really not the case that you ever need to use Time::Piece. But it does often make life easier. The default Perl installation on many versions of RHEL is broken (and Time::Piece is one of the bits that is missing). In order to fix it, you need to install the `perl-core` RPM. Ask your sysadmin to run `sudo yum install perl-core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `touch` method in [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#touch), and the rest is about splitting up the desired range of dates.  Note that the script below creates files (10 by default) with very simple-minded names, so please run in a brand new directory so to not overwrite something

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -MTime::Piece -wE'
    $n = shift // 10; 
    ($beg, $end) = map { 
        Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d")->epoch 
    } (20160101, 20181201); 
    $step = int ($end-$beg)/$n; 
    for (1..$n) { 
        $f = path("s$_.txt"); 
        $f->spew("data..$_\n"); 
        $f->touch($beg += $s)
' 5
```

Chaining calls to the desired `path(..)->spew(..)->touch(..)` doesn't work since `spew` returns true/false and not an object. (The `touch` does return the object and so it can have methods chained to it, but here it has to go after `spew` since `spew` changes the modification time.)

The above creates files

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx 8 Jul 31  2016 s1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx 8 Mar  1  2017 s2.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx 8 Sep 30  2017 s3.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx 8 May  1  2018 s4.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx 8 Nov 30  2018 s5.txt
```

You'll probably want to fiddle with the step size and first/last time stamps.

---

Apparently there is a problem with `Time::Piece`, likely indicating a problem with that system<sup>†</sup> since the module has been in core since 5.9.5.  Then I'd use `Time::Local::timelocal`

```
use Time::Local;    
my $seconds_epoch = timelocal $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year;
```

where `$mday` goes from `1` while all other start at `0`.  Note that while it is traditional to provide the year subject to `+1900` (so `116` for 2016) the normal years are accepted as well.  So

```
$beg = timelocal 0, 0, 0,  1,  0, 2016;
$end = timelocal 0, 0, 0, 31, 11, 2018;
```

or, for more flexibility with dates

```
($beg, $end) = map { 
    ($yr, $m, $d) = unpack "A4A2A2"; 
    timelocal 0, 0, 0, $d, $m-1, $yr 
} (20160101, 20181231)
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  The problem of the missing `Time::Piece` is described in [this post in Dave Cross's blog](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/).  Also see comments under the question and a chat.

Comment: Hi zdim.. thank you..  actually I was struggling without the Time::Piece module

Comment: @stack0114106 Huh?  I thought that `Time::Piece` was core since, um, forever.  The doc lists year 2000.  Are you sure that your system is OK?  If you somehow legitimately don't have that, what date-time module do you have?

Comment: Is it possible to get the epoch range without the time piece module?.. you can add it as variant in the same answer

Comment: @stack0114106 Was just about to ask :).   With it you have `$sec_epoch = timelocal sec, min, hour, day, mon, year;`  Testing here, will edit

Comment: @stack0114106 Edited

Comment: @zdim: [This explains](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/) what the problem is with the Time::Piece installation on that system.

Comment: @DaveCross Indeed, very nicely written up (as always), years ago.  I'd seen what it was from their "chat" but thank you for providing a solid resource. Added to my answer.